# Detect which string is replaced in php

Tags: php

Is it possible to tell which string or strings are replaced when using PHP's `str_replace` function?

In other words, I have a call similar to the following

```
$subject = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject, $count);
```

Where `$search` and `$replace` are both arrays. If `$count > 0` I want to figure out which strings were replaced and do something with them. Is something like this possible? Is there a function which does it? Should I just rewrite my code?

Comment: Well, in this instance, `$subject` is one singular string and `$search` has to be given a value ahead of time so you know exactly what has been found and replaced if `$count > 0`.

Comment: @the_pete Both my `$search` and `$replace` parameters are arrays though. If I'm understanding the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) correctly, I shouldn't know which elements were replaced by the count alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach is `array_diff()`

```
$str = array('something to rplace', 'anything else', 'sth else', 'one more');
$str2 = $str;

$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str, $count);

var_dump( array_diff($str2, $str) );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why I didn't think of something like this. My subject was a string and not an array though, but that's nothing `explode()` couldn't fix.